# How to Notify User that Asynchronous Task is Completed?

Tags: ajax, django, multithreading

I am using threading library for a long-running process in Django. When the process is completed, I want to keep updating progress status on the front-end. I am unable to post anything to the ajax.get() from my thread function.

View.py

```
def upload_handler(request, file_loc, filename):
    // do something with uploaded
    // I want to notify user that this process is complete via a post
class Uploader(View):
    def get(self, request):
        file=UploadForm()
        return render(request,'template.html',{'form':file}) #,'files':files})
    def post(self, request):
        file = UploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if file.is_valid():
            x = request.FILES['file']
            file.save()
            filename = str(request.FILES['file'])
            file_loc = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'images', filename)
            upload_thread = Thread(target=upload_handler, args=(request, file_loc, filename))
            upload_thread.start()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Uploader.as_view(), name='imageupload'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

ajax call script

```
{ 
    $.ajax({
      type:"get",
      url:"/uploader",
      datatype:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Your file is processed now!");
      }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Assume that file uploaded page will remain open till the long process completes.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX option datatype is "json", but the View does not return a "json".

Comment: The ajax post from view should be in upload_handler function and  I haven't posted anything from that function. Please read the problem carefully :)

Comment: Dose not the URL '/uploader'  match  'Uploader' ?  Please give out the complete url  settings.